# Set Global number format on all jquery dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have around **100** jquery datatables, all tables contain numeric columns with different order, some of them are int some are float, i want to set the global function which configure the dataTable set numeric format and should be apply on all **datatables** , the **targets** columns are different for every table

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {        
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0,1,3],
            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0)
        }]
    });
```

for int **(1234) = 1,234** and for float **1234.00 = 1,234.00**

Comment: It would be easier to provide assistance if you included some sample mark up for your data tables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no need to see the sample of data tables, I'm asking about the global setting of dataTable. I have posted the sample of code above for global setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**do these changes in code, code is in separate js file.**

```
   $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "columnDefs": [{
        targets: '_all',        
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {           

            if (Number.isInteger(data)) {
                return data.toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 });
            } else if (isNaN(parseInt(data))) {  
                return data;
            } else {
                return data.toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Faisal Shahab's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69961198/16480316) is a nice basis. In addition, one can integrate the conversion from Strings to integers or floats, and also return floats in scientific notation.

Thus, here is my attempt:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "columnDefs": [{
        targets: '_all',  
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            let float_data = parseFloat(data);
            if (Number.isInteger(float_data)) {
                return float_data.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 });
            } else if (isNaN(float_data)) {
                return data;
            } else {
                if (float_data < 0.01) {
                    return float_data.toExponential(2);
            } else {
                return float_data.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
            }
        }
    }]   
}
```